# Firefox encodes some characters as squares filled with numbers

Tags: firefox, browser, fonts, encoding, characters

Since a couple of days I'm experiencing this problem: Firefox (and Light too) displays a lot of strange characters in different websites. Something like:

 

And so on. I realized that those characters are mainly icon-fonts displayed wrong, and it's really annoing since it workend untill few days ago. Does someone have an idea about what could be the problem and how to fix it?

I already tried to delete cache/cookies/everything and checked if Firefox has setted the option that allow webpages to download and use their own fonts.

Moreover, I don't think that this is a Firefox-related issue, but probably a system problem since I tried using Light (a Firefox-based browser, from a different installation) and got the same result.

Anyway, more infos.

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate
- Firefox version: 27.0 (it's upgrading..)

Recently I haven't installed new addons or changed settings. The only relevant event happened was the upgrade to Firefox 27 days ago, but I can't tell if the problem appeared just after.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please specify: Firefox version, add-ons you have installed, the operating system you're using. Did you change any settings or something in the past few days?

Comment: @and31415 Got edits, sorry.

Comment: What about add-ons? Are you using any?

Comment: @and31415 Yes, but are the same since months, I haven't changed them and in the past, with the same addons installed, everything worked fine.

Comment: Maybe the add-ons are the same, but Firefox isn't since it has been updated just recently. Also, could you provide some links where you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Copy this in your address bar. To you, it should display a V (checked) icon, to me displays a square with two rows stating "F00C".
`data:text/html, <style>.x:before { content: "\f00c";} </style><span class="x"> </span>`

Comment: and Internet Explorer?

Comment: @edelwater I don't know about IE, but I just turned on the pc and now the icons are displayed.. It would be a interesting to know the cause of this problem anyway.